# Plotting with the R package hyperSpec and creating a hyperSpec basic object

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, spectral

I am currently trying to develop my plotting skills...again-.- Functional data is what I want to plot most of the time. Usually I am doing this just by using ggplot2 and wrangling the data into the correct format. But now I stumbled across the [package "hyperSpec"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/index.html) which is obviously designed for people like me. This package is actually using the environment of ggplot2. The problem is that I am struggling with creating the basic object needed to use this package. I do not know how my data should look like, even after reading the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/vignettes/fileio.pdf):frowning: Page 3 explains how to create such an object but I failed to understand that...

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I can help you if you provide me with the data you want to plot.

Comment: Function `as.long.df ` with option `rownames = TRUE` might be helpful to prepare `hyperSpec` data for plotting with `ggplot2`. Type `?hyperSpec::initialize` in `R` console to get help how to create  a new `hyperSpec` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help...Plotting the data is not the problem...I am aware that this can be solved by using ggplot2. My data has two statuses...Healthy/Infected. One sample is a function of the Wavelength...350nm - 2500nm. To plot it in ggplot2 I usually transform the data to a long-format. I am going to check out ?hyperSpec::initialize...thanks a lot Vilmantas.

Comment: Alright! Thank you Vilmantas! I made it :-) ?hyperSpec::initialize was more than useful...

Comment: Rene, I wrote my comment as an answer. Could you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Function `as.long.df` with option `rownames = TRUE` might be helpful to prepare `hyperSpec` data for plotting with `ggplot2`.
2. Type `?hyperSpec::initialize` in R console to get help how to create a new `hyperSpec` object.